# what cause kubernetes pods to show up slow?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-pod

I am using terraform to deploy helm releases. It took about 4 min until I saw a couple of pods show up (this issue is about pods showing up slow not starting up slow).

A couple of things I have checked:

1. liveness probe -> might not be related as this is about after the pod is created, my current issue is pods being created/showing up slow
2. request limit -> might not be related as this about after pod being created, the pod has a pending statue

I need some ideas why it behaves like this. thanks.

Comment: Your first guess is a very close one. Check Readiness probe.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-readiness-probes

Comment: readiness tells whether the container is ready to serve request. but my issue is why the container took longer to show up (no pods/containers in the k get po command)

Comment: What does "longer" mean? Was it starting up faster previously?